# Grails Updating Production Database

Tags: sql, grails, groovy, web-applications

What happens in Grails, when you update your model, and deploy it to your web server? Does the existing data get overwritten?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your model is changed you need to upgrade your db, you can use [this plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/database-migration).

Make sure you change you setting from create-drop to update.

There are a couple of good guides you can look at, [here](http://fbflex.wordpress.com/2011/01/19/working-with-the-grails-database-migration-plugin/) is a good one.

Good luck!

Comment: i really appreciate this. same to you!

Answer (score 3):

The behavior is defined in the [GORM configuration](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#automaticDatabaseMigration)

Basically, the default for development is drop-create, which erase all the content, and recreate tables.

On more stable releases, **update** might be a good setting knowing that Hibernate prefer to fails that conflict.

As always, I would recommend making a backup of the DB before performing such operation on pre-production and production systems.